# How to set file permission in azure run pipeline

Tags: azure, docker

I want to set file permission to 777 in specific file in my website It's possible to do it?
if possible can you tell me how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change permission of a folder to 777 in Dockerfile?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1006938/how-to-change-permission-of-a-folder-to-777-in-dockerfile)

Comment: (You almost never want to set something to mode 0777, which allows any user to overwrite any other user's files.  Do you mean 0755?)

Comment: i want to set file for store log data ex) server.log but now i used monolog php and response is could not be opened; it may be invalid or not writable."